# how to download bitbucket code to new machine

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git and my code is in bitbucket. I changed my laptop. I want to know the steps to set up entire thing in my new laptop. By the way, I am using ubuntu, ubuntu commands will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/bgozDQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use git clone and clone from your bitbucket repository.